# Is a Yohrtzeit or Yizkor candle which is lit 2 days before a yohrtzeit, or Yom-Tov as good as 1 lit on (or just prior to) the yohrtzeit or YT itself?

Tags: yom-tov, yizkor

When Yom Tov begins right after Shabbos (as with Shavuos of this year), can one light a 2-day Yizkor candle before Shabbos and have it continue burning until Yomtov, or there is no purpose in doing so because the candle was not lit on or just prior to the Yizkor day?

Would A candle lit for a Yohrtzeit have the same rules as a Yizkor candle?

If one may light it even 2 days before, is this Lechatchila anytime, or only when it cannot be done otherwise, as in the case of Shabbos?

Comment: SEE טור ושו”ע או”ח סי’ תקיד סעי’ ה ובמגן אברהם שם, ובמשנה ברורה שם ס”ק ל - as to the question if one may light a נר נשמה on Yom -Tov.

Comment: What's the difference between a Yahrtzeit candle and a Yizkor candle?

Comment: Is there such a thing as Lechatkhila and Bedieved for something which isn't a formal Mitzva?

Comment: @DoubleAA A Just what the purpose of lighting it is.

Comment: "just prior to" What does that mean exactly and how is it different from this case where you light it at the last possible moment before

Comment: I don't know what the purpose if lighting either is, frankly. If it's just to do the same thing your ancestors did, then just do what they did in this case (probably light before Shabbat)

Comment: @DoubleAA AFAIK minhagim also have a right way to do them. So why should there not be aLechatchila way for regular situations and a B'dieved way for שעת הדחק where one cannot do it the best way?

Comment: If the Minhag is that in shaat hadechak situations you do something different then that's the Lechatkhila thing to do then. There's no different Kiyum.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Schachter [writes](http://file:///C:/Users/natem/AppData/Local/Temp/Shavuot_To-Go_-_5774_Rabbi_Schachter.pdf):

> Some poskim question whether one is permitted to light a yahrtzeit
> candle on the second  day of Yom Tov in honor of Yizkor. The Kitzur
> Shulchan Aruch (98:1) cites poskim on both  sides of the issue and
> concludes that one should not light such a candle on Yom Tov. He
> views it as a “ner shel avtala,” a candle whose light does not provide
> benefit on Yom Tov, and  as such may not be lit. Therefore, one should
> ideally light a yahrtzeit candle on erev Yom  Tov.

Answer (score 0):

The book [“Mourning in Halacha”](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0899061710) does not mention your specific case.

But it does say that if the Yahrzeit falls on Yom Tov  and one forget to kindle the light on the preceding afternoon, one should kindle it from an existing flame in the manner permitted on Yom Tov in the room where people eat, so that they will benefit from the light. But it is more correct to kindle it in the synagogue; however under pressing circumstances, it is possible to permit kindling it elsewhere.  (He quotes the Biur Halocho 514 s.v. Ner shel batalah).

I see from here that one can light the Yahrzeit light on Yom Tov itself which offers you a practical solution, if not an answer to your direct question.

On the purpose of the Yahrzeit light, the end of the Biur Halocho reads,

> It may be possible to allow the Yahrzeit light anyway because it is a
>   bit like a light for a mitzvah because it is for the honour of his
>   ancestors – so it is explained by the Ksav Sofer.

Comment: What I see from there is that it is better to light it on the preceding afternoon rather than on YT, since he says "if one forget to kindle the light on the preceding afternoon" only then shouls it be kindled on YT.  My question still stands whether this is also so when the previous afternoon is Shabbos, is it better to light it on the afternoon of Erev Shabbos which is 2 days before, rather than on YT, or then it is too far back and it is as if he could not light it at the proper time and he can /should light it on YT itself?